# Text indentation with HTML Tag in Phpstrom

Tags: phpstorm

I want the same indentation for text as the tag has.
Anyone can tell the exact settings for Phpstrom editor

[image: Phpstrom html file]]

Comment: I have all the text indented with the default code style preferences. What file type is it - HTML or PHP? Looks as if you have some language injected in `<body>` tag. Please check your language injections in *Settings | Editor | Language Injections*

Comment: It would be good if you could expand on your question somewhat. It is not very clear.

Comment: It's a HTML file.

I checked language injection, all options are checked but i don't know what to do with those.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/mB7NHpc) See this image.


and how to get rid of those highlights, spread on the empty space.